# Trying to tar a file and send through scp via sshpass but sshpass not functioning

Tags: bash, scp, sshpass

I have set -x added to see the lines that get executed when the code runs, all of the lines are being executed but the actual package.tar.gz file, which is represented as $FILE in the scp command, is not getting sent to the host.

If I copy out the sshpass line and change $FILE to package.tar.gz and paste that as a command into the terminal, the file will be sent successfully. Like so `/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' scp package.tar.gz ubuntu@192.168.1.33:/home/ubuntu/.`

```
 #!/bin/bash
 set -x
 FILE="package.tar.gz"     
 SRCDIR="/var/www/html/mysite"          
 tar -cPzf $FILE $SRCDIR/*     
 /usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' scp $FILE ubuntu@192.168.1.33:/home/ubuntu/.
```

Could it be that sshpass is being executed before the package.tar.gz is created?

Comment: No, `sshpass` will not run until `tar` completes. What is the trace output resulting from `set -x`?

Comment: @chepner this is the output of set -x https://pastebin.com/ah6tv5NZ let me know if you need anything else

Comment: The script itself is fine; you should add `-v` to the `scp` command to figure out why it isn't transferring the file correctly.